# Split By 2 String Delimiters via RegEx Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split, delimiter

I am relatively new to RegEx and need help splitting up a section of text by two delimiters, and then capturing what's between them. For instance, I have a JSON object that has a "description" property, and it essentially contains this text:

```
This is yet another test product to test for all sorts of styling/formatting issues. 

PLACEHOLDER

PLACEHOLDER

PLACEHOLDER

******

Not so expensive
Works all day
Works throughout the night
No risk
100% Guarantee
------

This would be where ingredients would go for Test Product 4.
```

What I am trying to do is to capture the "bulleted" list between the six-asterisk delimiter and the 6-dash delimiter. So in the above example, I want to be able to capture these lines:

```
Not so expensive
Works all day
Works throughout the night
No risk
100% Guarantee
```

Thus, I need to split by two delimiters:

```
1) ******
2) ------
```

After searching around this and other forums, I still can't seem to get any form of .split() method and RegEx to get precisely what I want. Is anyone able to help me out here? The ultimate goal is to be able to capture that text and then append it to a `<div>`

Answer (score 2):

No? Really?

```
string.split(/------|\*\*\*\*\*\*/);
```

Comment: @MikeM: Forgot about that, but my point still hold. `/-{6}|\*{6}/`. It is less prone to error.

Comment: Thanks. This def works, but I'd already tried it and other solutions. I realize now that it was the platform wrapping the JSON data in a bizarre fashion and getting in the way. Fixed the problem.